# I need to find a cubic equation that has a discriminant equal to zero

Tags: cubics

I have been working on a script in Java to solve cubic equations. I've been following along with Mathematics and Physics for Programmers to teach my self about, well maths and physics.

As far as I can test it is working correctly, but I have not been able to find an equation with a discriminant of zero to test that case.

The equation that the code is based on is as follows:

[image: eq]

If the discriminant is > 0:

[image: disc1]

if the discriminant = 0 (**I do not know an equation to test this**):

[image: disc2]

if the discriminant < 0:

[image: disc3]

After finding *t* transform it by:

[image: transform]

I'd be very grateful if someone can help me work out how to test this is working correctly.

For anyone interested my code is here: https://github.com/sarcoma/Java-Algorithms/blob/master/src/com/oacc/maths/SolveCubic.java

Comment: Check it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_discriminant

Comment: A polynomial (cubic or otherwise) has discriminant equal to 0 if and only if it has a multiple root.

Comment: $y=x^3$ should work.

Comment: To expand on Oiler's comment, if you're not familiar with the terminology - any cubic of the form $a(x-b)^2(x-c)$ will do (and, indeed, this is a characterization of cubics with discriminant $0$).

Comment: @user58697 Thanks for the link, I found that and skimmed it, I'll give it a thorough reading.

Comment: @Oiler I sort of understand that (I think), what I need to do is find one. Kind of the other way around I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I'd expand on my comment. If you have a polynomial $f(x) = a_{n}x^n + \cdots + a_{0}$ and its roots are $r_{1}, \dots, r_{n}$ then the discriminant $D$ is equal to $$ D = a_{n}^{2n - 2} \prod_{i < j} (r_{i} - r_{j})^2.$$

From this definition, it is immediate that $f$ has discriminant 0 if and only if it has a repeated root.

So if you want a cubic with discriminant zero, try something like $(x - 4)^2(x + 5)$ such as John Gowers suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is all going over my head, I can understand the form `Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D = 0` which I'm simplifying to `x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0` I'm trying to find `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` that I can punch in to my function, I'm not sure how would translate: `(x−4)2(x+5)`.

Comment: First, note that we aren't setting a polynomial equal to zero anywhere (though this is certainly necessary for determining the roots). Now if you want to write $(x - 4)^2 (x +5)$ in the form $Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$, you have to expand the polynomial-- $(x - 4)^2 = x^2 - 8x + 16$ so $(x -4)^2(x + 5) = (x^2 - 8x + 16)(x +5)$. I'll leave the rest of the algebra to you.

Comment: Thanks so much, when I manage that you'll get your tick :)

Comment: $x^{3} - 3 x^{2} - 24 x + 80$ has Δ = 0

Comment: And to top it off the code works too! Thanks so much for your help. Do you know what I'd need to google to find out more about: $a(x−b)^{2}(x−c)$, no worries if not.

Comment: @Sarcoma that's kind of vague. What exactly do you want to know more about?

Comment: Ha, no problem, it's just that John Gowers mentioned "this is a characterization of cubics with discriminant 0", I wondered if there was something I could research to find out more. But as long as it does what I need, it's fine.

Comment: Well my answer outlines exactly why that's the case-- the discriminant is zero if and only if a polynomial has a repeated root. So if a cubic has discriminant zero, it will look something like $a(x-b)^2)(x-c)$ where $b$ isn't necessarily distinct from $c$.